# Streaming Sample Probability

Tags: probability

Could someone please explain the following question in layman's terms (even simpler than how the question is currently explained)? I'm looking to improve at probability..

> You know how to use rand to randomly sample an element from an array.
>
> Now, write a function that, given an input stream of objects, will
>   sample a value. The stream has limited length.
>
> Use only O(1) memory. Every value in the stream should have an equal
>   probability of being sampled.

Code:

```
def streaming_sample(stream)
  sample = stream
  num_els = 1 #needs to set to the first stream because otherwise first one never gets picked

  while true
    next_value = stream.next_value
    break if next_value.nil?

    # keep sample with probability num_els / (num_els + 1)
    keep_prob = num_els.fdiv(num_els + 1)
    sample = next_value if rand() < keep_prob

    num_els += 1
  end

  sample
end
```

The reasoning of the solution is:

> Let's prove this works by induction. First, note that for num_els = 1,
>   this says we keep the previous sample (nil), with probability 0. So
>   after 1 element, every element has an equal chance of being sampled
>   (the only element is selected with probability 1).
>
> Next, assume that we've iterated through m elements, and that the
>   streaming sample has selected an element (so far) with equal
>   probability 1/m. Then the probability of keeping the current sampled
>   element after considering the m + 1th element is 1 / m * m / (m + 1)
>   == 1 / (m + 1). Likewise, the probability of selecting the m + 1th element is 1 / (m + 1).

Answer (score 0):

sample = next_value if rand() > keep_prob

should be

sample = next_value if rand() > keep_prob

For example, if keep_prob = 9/10, then you should set sample = next_value with probability 1/10.  rand() will be < keep_prob with probability keep_prob.